# How to make generated routes lower case in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

If we ask the MVC framework to generate URLs for us, for example by using `UrlHelper` inside a controller, the route segments in the generated URL will be upper case.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var url = this.Url.Action("Get", "People"); // Returns "/People"

        ...
    }
}
```

How is it possible to tell MVC to generate lower case routes instead, so in the above example, return "/people"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple to achieve this, in the `ConfigureServices` method of our `Startup` class we just have to configure routing by setting the `LowerCaseUrls` property to true.

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting(routeOptions => routeOptions.LowercaseUrls = true);

        ...
    }
}
```